# Не работает токен в discord.py client

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Пытался использовать библиотеку discum, она работает, но нет тех функций, которые мне нужны (изменение RichPresenсe) (не работает просто), есть ли другая библиотека для работы с RichPresenсe или как можно пофиксить это?

токен валидный, discum с ним спокойно работает

```
[2022-11-02 21:45:13] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BruhMoment\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 801, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\BruhMoment\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 744, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BruhMoment\Desktop\discord\main1.py", line 21, in <module>
    client.run(token)
  File "C:\Users\BruhMoment\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 828, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "C:\Users\BruhMoment\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\BruhMoment\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\BruhMoment\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 817, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\BruhMoment\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 745, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "C:\Users\BruhMoment\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 580, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token)
  File "C:\Users\BruhMoment\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 805, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001F41B2E50D0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BruhMoment\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\BruhMoment\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\BruhMoment\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\BruhMoment\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

```
import discord
import json


with open("settings.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    token = data["token"]


intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, presences=True)

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as ' + str(client.user))


client.run(token)
```

Comment: Для чего задаете вопрос, если ответ уже написан в тексте ошибки? `discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.` — `Был передан неправильный токен`

Comment: эм, ты собираешься подставить токен от своего аккаунта как токен бота?